# How to compile template directives with ui-rout and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, templates, compilation, load, angular-ui-router

I have the following state.

```
    .state('categories', {
        url: '/categories',
        templateUrl: 'categories',
        controller: 'CategoriesController',
    })
```

And template url loads:

```
<div>
    <a ui-sref="categories.bob">my link text</a>
</div>
```

But `ui-sref` isn't compiled. How is the right way to slove this case ?

--[EDIT]--
I mean html loaded form template is not compiled by AnulgarJS. For example

```
 <a ui-sref="categories.bob">my link text</a>
```

should be

```
 <a ui-sref="categories.bob" href="#/categories/bob">my link text</a>
```

Comment: Because you don't have a state `categories.bob`, you just have a state `categories`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to pass `bob` as an optional parameter? If that is the case try the following:

Defining a new state:

```
.state('categories.name', {
    url: '/:name',
    templateUrl: 'subcategorytemplate',
    controller: 'SubCategoryController',
})
```

The route:

```
<div>
    <a ui-sref="categories.name({name:"bob"})">my link text</a>
</div>
```

You will find your route parameter in ui-router's `$stateParams` service by calling `$stateParams.name`. For further information look [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters).

Comment: Are you sure `ui-router` work that way...? My solution would render `href="#/categories/bob"`, maybe try that ;)

Comment: @FlorianGl The reason why you will render to `href="#/categories/bob" ` is because you probably didn't set up the base tag `<base href=""></base>`in your index.html. You should avoid that.

Comment: ? `href="#/categories/bob"` is perfectly fine. what else should it render?^^

Comment: @FlorianGl I mean what it will display on your url? `localhost:3000/#/categories/bob?` or `localhost:3000/categories/bob`.

Comment: it's not about me. i'm not the OP, why are you trying to help me? i've writte this code out of my memory, i don't use it...and the hashtag is desired, otherwise it would be a server route, not a client route.

Comment: How to make my controller bind active variable after i load template ? <a ui-sref="categories.bob" class="{{active}}">my link text</a>

Comment: @СвободенРоб i just saw i misunderstood your problem. you need to define a new state. have a look at my edit. where does you active variable come from? the url?

Answer (score 0):

In fact i found my problem. My nasted state url's was wrong.

```
.state('categories.category', {
        url: '/:category',
        templateUrl: function($params) {
            console.log($params); 
            return 'categories/' + $params.category;
        },
    })
```

But I still don't understend how and why `<a ui-sref="someUrl">` are rendered like `<a ui-sref="someUrl" href="#>someUrl">` buy if I load html with templateUrl no href attribute is generated. So is there a way to make it generate href attribute too ?

How to load my nested view in parent `ui-view` ?